# How to read file and save hyphen using STL C++

Tags: c++, vector, stl, ifstream, read-write

I have to read text file, convert it to lower case and remove non-alphabetic characters but also need to save hyphen and do not count it as a word. here is my coding. It is counting hyphen as word in `UnknownWords` . I just want to save hyphen and just only want to count words which are on the left and right side of the hyphen in the `.txt`.

My output:

```
110 Known words read
79 Unknown words read //it is because it is counting hyphen as word
```

Desired output is:

```
110 Known words read
78 Unknown words read
```

Code:

```
void WordStats::ReadTxtFile(){
    std::ifstream ifile(Filename);
    if(!ifile)
    {
        std::cerr << "Error Opening file " << Filename << std::endl;
        exit(1);
    }
    for (std::string word; ifile >> word; )
    {

        transform (word.begin(), word.end(), word.begin(), ::tolower);
        word.erase(std::remove_if(word.begin(), word.end(), [](char c)
        {
            return (c < 'a' || c > 'z') && c != '\'' && c != '-';
        }),  word.end());
        if (Dictionary.count(word))
        {
            KnownWords[word].push_back(ifile.tellg());
        }
        else
        {
            UnknownWords[word].push_back(ifile.tellg()); 
        }
    }
    //  std::string word; ifile >> word;


    std::cout << KnownWords.size() << " known words read." << std::endl;
    std::cout << UnknownWords.size() << " unknown words read." << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: What does the input file look like?

Comment: I tested your code, if `word == "this#-is"` it changes it to `"this-is"`, so I think it should be working. Do you have spaces around the hyphen in the file?

Comment: it is text file like an article or paragraph which includes some colons and inverted commas and hyphens.

Comment: yes i do have spaces around hyphen

Comment: `ifile >> word` stops at the spaces.

Comment: You need to read the whole line, then write you own parser that finds words, and treats two tokens with `-` between them as a single word.

Comment: Why do you have spaces around the hyphens? That's not the normal way that hyphenated words are written.

Comment: This is text file given to me by my instructor . I have to read through this file. Please, Look at the desired output , you will have an idea what actually do i need to do.

Comment: I understand what you need to do.

Comment: If you're going to use `>>` to read the words, you have to check for the next word being `"-"`. Then you concatenate the words before and after the hyphen, and put that in the word vector.

Comment: It would probably be easier if you put all the words into a vector first, it would then be easier to look for hyphens and combine the words around it.

Comment: i have alot of hyphens in my text file. But i need to save hyphen that comes with words for example, non-linear. It is one word. but if it is " - TOP TEN TRICKS - ". then hyphens shoudl be removed becuase they are single.

Comment: That's why I asked you to show a sample of the input and the desired result **in the question**.

Comment: I think I get it. You want to keep `"good-looking"`, but you don't want to keep `"-"` all by itself.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to put a word that's just `"-"` by itself, check for that before adding to the word vectors:

```
for (std::string word; ifile >> word; )
{

    transform (word.begin(), word.end(), word.begin(), ::tolower);
    word.erase(std::remove_if(word.begin(), word.end(), [](char c)
    {
        return (c < 'a' || c > 'z') && c != '\'' && c != '-';
    }),  word.end());
    if (word.find_first_not_of("-") == string::npos) { // Ignore word that's only hyphens
        continue;
    }
    if (Dictionary.count(word))
    {
        KnownWords[word].push_back(ifile.tellg());
    }
    else
    {
        UnknownWords[word].push_back(ifile.tellg()); 
    }
}
```